# read url content WHILE it is continuously updating

Tags: java, android, url

I have a php script that makes a few api calls in a row and once an api call has
returned data the script outputs the content. Meaning if you call the script on
the browser you will wait 1 second then see some content appear, than after 2 seconds
more content will be appended to the page and so on.

The thing is I am accessing this content from java/android in one of my apps.
Is there a way I can read this content from java WHILE it is updating? This
way I will populate the application content as new data is being fetched from
the script.

I have tried something like this when I have accessed xml files but they
were not continuously updating.

```
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `URLConnection` instead of `HttpClient`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)'s a tutorial.

Like in the tutorial, `connection.getInputStream()` will return a stream you can read and process, for example line-wise.